# Open Street Map using OSMN: how to get building height?

Tags: openstreetmap, osmnx

I am trying to find a way to extract building heights. Here is what I've tried so far:

```
place_name = "Uptown, Dallas, Texas"
buildings = ox.geometries_from_place(place_name, tags={'building':True}) 
print(buildings.columns)
```

outputs:

```
Index(['amenity', 'geometry', 'nodes', 'addr:housenumber', 'addr:street',
       'building', 'building:levels', 'height', 'name', 'office', 'wikidata',
       'wikipedia', 'parking', 'addr:city', 'addr:postcode', 'addr:state',
       'layer', 'cuisine', 'access', 'addr:country', 'brand', 'brand:wikidata',
       'brand:wikipedia', 'opening_hours', 'operator', 'operator:wikidata',
       'operator:wikipedia', 'phone', 'ref:walmart', 'shop', 'website',
       'wheelchair', 'beds', 'emergency', 'gnis:feature_id', 'healthcare',
       'old_name', 'ele', 'gnis:county_name', 'gnis:import_uuid',
       'gnis:reviewed', 'source', 'fee', 'smoking', 'roof:levels',
       'roof:shape', 'addr:unit', 'tourism', 'short_name', 'contact:website',
       'outdoor_seating', 'ways', 'type'],
      dtype='object')
```

`height` parameters are `NaN` for most values. The closet parameter is `building:levels` but it is just number of stories in buildings.

Comment: What does the `height` field contain?

Comment: @JerryCoffin `height` parameters are `NaN` for most values. Updated question.

Comment: I'd guess the NaN means they simply don't have the height for that building. If you really need heights, you may need a different source (e.g., [NASA SRTM heightmaps](https://www.usgs.gov/centers/eros/science/usgs-eros-archive-digital-elevation-shuttle-radar-topography-mission-srtm?qt-science_center_objects=0#qt-science_center_objects), though these are now quite dated).